# Why is there always a non-trivial $u$ such that $Lu = u$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

In my ODE class we are studying Sturm–Liouville theory and my professor mentioned that given a differential operator
$$
Lu = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} a_n(t) \, u^{(n)}(t)
$$
then for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ there is a non-trivial $u:[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $Lu = \lambda u$.

However, I am not able to see why this is true. For example, even in the most basic case where $Lu = a_0(t)\,u(t)$ the we get

$$Lu = \lambda u \implies a_0(t)\,u = \lambda u \implies a_0(t) \equiv \lambda$$

But this means that we can't do this for arbitrary $L$. Am I missing or misinterpreting something?

Comment: The relevant result here is that if $f$ is Lipschitz, then the the differential equation $y' = f(y, x), y(0) = y_0$ has a unique solution on a neighborhood of $0$. It's possible to extend it to higher-order equations, but you're right that you need some nontriviality constraints on the $a_n$ to avoid the case where $L$ is just multiplication by some function.

Comment: Do you need $n>0$ in much the same way that in the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, a polynomial *of positive degree* has a root over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You also need (at a minimum) that $a_n(t)$ is nonzero on the interior of your region. For example, $tu’=-u$ has no nontrivial solutions in a neighborhood of 0. Outside of 0, $1/t$ works.

Comment: Thanks all. So looks like my example was particularly bad. If I try $Lu = a_1(t) u'(t)$ then for a given $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ I can use $u = C \exp{\left\{\int \lambda a_1(t)dt\right\}}$ for any $C \in \mathbb{C}$. I will try to work out a more general proof for fun.